# Qt find word function with QWebEngine

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

I create a simple web browser with Qt 5.7 and the webEngine. 
I would like to create an search function to find word in webView but I don't really know how make interaction between web content and Qt ( I'm new on Qt, I do this for fun and to improve my level ).

this is the minimal code too display WebView : 
main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.showMaximized();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void setWebEngine();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QWebEngineView *view;    
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWebEngine();
    setCentralWidget(view);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::setWebEngine()
{
    view = new QWebEngineView();
    view->load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
}
```

I would like to know something else, is it possible to list elements in the web content ( form, h1, h2, ... )

Have a nice day, and sorry for my English ;)

Comment: What do you mean with your second question? I'm sorry, but please consider reading the documentation (doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html) before asking. How to use links in comments xD?

Comment: I want to say if is it possible to find the elements in web page like the <input>, <form>, ... and for example, get their content or modify it.

Comment: And thank you for your answer, for find text. If you have any idea for my second question, that can help me for another project =)

Comment: That seems to be another question. I think this is an extra question worth.

Comment: So, I will create another post haha, thank for your help ;)

Comment: I'll follow your next question ;D. Just trying to help people :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Qt5 documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#findText)

```
void QWebEngineView::findText(const QString &subString, QWebEnginePage::FindFlags options = QWebEnginePage::FindFlags())
```

> Finds the specified string, subString, in the page, using the given
>   options.
>
> To clear the selection, just pass an empty string.
>
> See also selectedText() and selectionChanged().

Should be quite simple.